# pdf.js unable to locate libraries in Drupal 7

Tags: files, theming

I followed the installation instructions that was located in both the module that you download from the modules section in Drupal as well as also downloaded the precompiled pdf.js and pdfworker.js files from the PDF.JS information page hosted by drupal.

However despite my efforts I am unable to get the modules page of Drupal to see the librarie for pdf.js

I have tried to alter the pdf.module by change the build/pdf.js lines of code to libraries/pdf.js/build/pdf.js as suggested in IRC chat but this didn't do the trick as well.

I was last looking at the simlink solution offered but noticed that there was a additional folder of external?  And not sure since that post was 2 years old and wondered if it was still a valid solution.  See reference -> https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/65768/pdf-js-installation-in-drupal-7

Running a windows environment with drupal 7

Not sure what else to do suggestions would be grand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently because of my relatively new start in drupal the missing libraries was a requirement module that I was overlooking and instead thought that it could see the libraries section in the file tree.

My Bad

Answer (score 0):

**Step1**: Download from here: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js

**Step2**: Download Windows installer: http://nodejs.org/download

**Step3**: Download & Install: https://www.drupal.org/project/pdf

**Step4**: Add the install folder of nodejs, to your PATH variable, so you can call 'node' command from command line

**Step5**: Through command line, goto /sites/all/libraries/pdf.js. Type 'node make generic'

**Note**: Make sure that in your library folder you have the pdf.js folder named exactly to "pdf.js". Then inside of that extract the pdf.js files. It should look like this.

[image]

Comment: That is indeed how the file structure looks

Comment: I have followed the instructions provided to the letter and still the silly thing is unable to find the libraries.